# Optimize code to reduce image size

Tags: android, bitmap, thumbnails, image-resizing

I have a method called onPictureTaken, it basically saves an image from the camera to the local sdcard in its original format, depending on device camera quality.

My question is, how can I optimize this method to include a **thumbnail** and an **efficient scaled replica**, so I can use the ***thumbnail for previews*** and the ***scaled replica for uploads to my server***.

Here is the method onPictureTaken:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

    File picStorage = new File("/sdcard/StrategicAppPics/");

    if(picStorage.exists()){}
    else{
        picStorage.mkdirs();
    }

    sampleDB = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(CreateClient.createdClient+".db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);     
    clientName = CreateClient.createdClient;

    uriTarget = Uri.fromFile( new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"StrategicAppPics/"+clientName+"_"+CreateBuilding.buildingName+".jpg" ));

    pictureTaken = 1;
    OutputStream imageFileOS;

    try{
        imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
        imageFileOS.write(arg0);
        imageFileOS.flush();
        imageFileOS.close();
        Toast.makeText(TakePicture.this,"Image saved!" + uriTarget.toString(),,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(TakePicture.this, CreateBuilding.class);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    camera.startPreview();
}};
```

Can anyone provide a practical solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Chris.